# own timer component with react, reflux not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I try to get used to reflux and forked a example repo. My full code is here [ https://github.com/svenhornberg/react-starterkit ]

I want to create a timer component which gets the current time from a timestore, but it is not working. The DevTools does not show any errors. This must be some newbie mistakes, but I do not find them.

**Edit1**: I added a line in home //edit1

**Edit2**: I think the mistake may be in componentDidMount in home.jsx

**FIXED** I need to trigger my time, see my answer.

**Store**

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';
import TimeActions from '../actions/timeActions';

var TimeStore = Reflux.createStore({
    listenables: timeActions,

    init() {
        this.time = '';
    },

    onCurrenttime() {
        this.time = '13:47';
    }
});
```

export default TimeStore;

**Actions**

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';

var TimeActions = Reflux.createActions([
  'currenttime'
]);

export default TimeActions;
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';

class Timer extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();    
  }

  render() {
    var time = this.props.time;

    return (
      <div>
        { time }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

Timer.propTypes = {
  time : React.PropTypes.string
}

export default Timer;
```

I wanted to use the timer component in the **home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ItemList from '../components/itemList.jsx';
import ItemStore from '../stores/itemStore';
import ItemActions from '../actions/itemActions';

import Timer from '../components/timer.jsx';
import TimeStore from '../stores/timeStore';
import TimeActions from '../actions/timeActions';

class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items : [],
      loading: false,
      time : '' //edit1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = ItemStore.listen(this.onStatusChange.bind(this));
    this.unsubscribe = TimeStore.listen(this.onStatusChange.bind(this));

    ItemActions.loadItems();
    TimeActions.currenttime();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  onStatusChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home Area</h1>
        <ItemList { ...this.state } />
        <Timer { ...this.state } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to: [How to Make React.js component listen to a store in Reflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538701/how-to-make-react-js-component-listen-to-a-store-in-reflux)

I have to trigger my time:

```
var TimeStore = Reflux.createStore({
    listenables: TimeActions,

    init() {
        this.time = '';
    },

    onCurrenttime() {
      this.trigger({
        time : '13:47'
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: need to wait 2 days until i can accept my own answer